# Gridview Calculated Field in Row

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, date-arithmetic

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Basic linked to a SQL database.  I have a Gridview in which I want to have a calculated field, let's call it NoHoursOff, based on the fields in that row - BeginTimeOff and EndTimeOff.

After doing some research, I learned that I should use a TemplateField.  I just don't understand how this works.  I have tried with no success:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Hours" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# "EndTimeOff" - "BeginTimeOff" %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I also have tried replacing Text value with "EndTimeOff".subtract("BeginTimeOff") which works on another webpage.  I don't understand how to do a calculated field!  Please help or can you direct me to a tutorial that would explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function in the codebehind like this

```
public string getValue(object BeginTimeOff, object EndTimeOff)
    {
        return (Convert.ToDateTime(EndTimeOff.ToString()) - Convert.ToDateTime(BeginTimeOff.ToString())).ToString();
    }
```

and in the `Label` this

```
Text=<%# getValue(Eval("BeginTimeOff"), Eval("EndTimeOff")) %>
```

then just set the format you want to display in the method (n days, hh.mm.ss, etc) to fit your requirement

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using Visual Basic.  Can you convert the code for me?  It's not working in the converter.  Thanks!

Comment: Try any of this DateTime.Parse() or DateTime.ParseExact()

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TotalHours2" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# getValue(Eval("BeginTimeOff"), Eval("EndTimeOff")) %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

Per your suggestions, I can't get it to work.  Here is my aspx and vb code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TotalHours2" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# getValue(Eval("BeginTimeOff"), Eval("EndTimeOff")) %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

AND

```
Public Function getValue(BeginTimeOff As Object, EndTimeOff As Object) As String
            Return (DateTime.Parse(EndTimeOff.ToString()) - DateTime.Parse(BeginTimeOff.ToString())).ToString()
End Function
```

It's probably something wrong with my attempt to convert C# to VB.  Thanks for all your help!  (FYI - I did get another function to work using your example - just not this new function.  If you want to see code, I'll show it to you.  It counts days between 2 dates, not including weekends and holidays.  Thanks a million for helping me figure that one out!)

Comment: and what is the error you get? can you compile the code without errors? I think that if you try `Convert.ToDateTime(EndTimeOff.ToString())`  instead of `DateTime.Parse(EndTimeOff.ToString())` it could finally work

Comment: For code - Return (Convert.ToDateTime(EndTimeOff.ToString()) - Convert.ToDateTime(BeginTimeOff.ToString())), I'm getting a String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  In the errors before I run the code, I see "Value of type 'System.TimeSpan' cannot be converted to 'String'."

Comment: I'm going to create another post because I figured out part of what I want to do.  Thanks for your help!